# Can i find out all my *class* variables?

Tags: java, classloader

From this question, [Can two copies of class variable exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824323/can-two-copies-of-class-variable-exist/7825101#7825101), i was told that multiple instances of the static variable may exist if the class is loaded multiple times, am i able to find out all the occurrences of the "duplicated" classes loaded by the classloader?

Comment: I don't think you understand the answer you're citing. A single classloader can't load the same class twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, no you cannot. You can get current class loader and tear it apart using reflection (look for `classes` field) looking for classes it has already loaded.

That already causes problems, because it assumes you know what's inside the `ClassLoader` instance—which is rarely a legitimate assumption.

You can go further up the class loader tree using `getParent()` and dig for `classes` in parents. What you cannot do though, is find all the class loaders—you can go up the tree, but not down the tree. The problem is, you are rarely interested in the parent class loaders—siblings are of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Go back and follow the links on the question, there are quite a few other question and answers combos that I think explain it, but basically I think different static instances can exist if the class is loaded by different class loaders, they will more then likely be completely seperate from each other, so for what you are asking you can not have duplicated instances

EDIT: specifically this one [is it possible to have multiple instances of static variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349797/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-instances-of-static-variables)